# Android app retrieving data from api (model to activity)

Tags: java, android, api, android-activity

I am making a cocktail android app.

I search for a cocktail's name then receive a list view of all the cocktails within the API I'm using. I click on the item (cocktail) in the list view and then display the information of the cocktail (name, thumbnail, ingredients, etc.) in a new activity (called CocktailDisplay). I pass the name of the cocktail from the SearchCocktail activity through intent. From there, I am simply displaying that text in the CocktailDisplay.

I want to just start by displaying the image and name of the cocktail.

I am having trouble, new help, accessing the model to acquire the information needed for the thumbnail and eventually the ingredient(s) and other info.

I'm new to android development so I'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

Thanks in advance! Here's my code.

SearchActivity.java (Section passing data to CocktailDisplay.java)

```
        ListView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
            DrinkRecipeModel value = (DrinkRecipeModel) ListView1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // selected item
            String cocktail = value.getDrinkName();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CocktailDisplay.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            myIntent.putExtra("selected-item", cocktail);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
```

DrinkRecipeModel.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DrinkRecipeModel {
    @SerializedName("idDrink")
    private int drinkId;

    @SerializedName("strDrink")
    private String drinkName;

    @SerializedName("categories")
    private String drinkCategories;

    @SerializedName("strDrinkThumb")
    private String drinkThumb;

    @SerializedName("ingredients")
    private ArrayList<String> ingredients;

    public int getDrinkId() {
        return drinkId;
    }

    public String getDrinkName(){
        return drinkName;
    }

    public String getDrinkCategories(){
        return drinkCategories;
    }

    public String getDrinkThumb(){
        return drinkThumb;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getIngredients() { return ingredients; }


    public void setDrinkId(int drinkId) { this.drinkId = drinkId; }

    public void setDrinkName(String drinkName) { this.drinkName = drinkName; }

    public void setDrinkCategories(String drinkCategories) {
        this.drinkCategories = drinkCategories;
    }

    public void setDrinkThumb(String drinkThumb) {
        this.drinkThumb = drinkThumb;
    }

    public void setIngredients(ArrayList<String> ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }
}
```

activity_cocktail_display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CocktailDisplayActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cocktailImage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"
    android:minHeight="10dp"
    android:minWidth="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cocktailName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cocktailImage"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CocktailDisplay.java

```
public class CocktailDisplay extends Activity {
    TextView cocktailName;
    ImageView cocktailImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cocktail_display);

    cocktailName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cocktailName);
    cocktailImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cocktailImage);

    // get the intent from which this activity is called.
    Intent intent = getIntent();

   // ***** Trying to access model data here...not happy *****
    DrinkRecipeModel recipe = *not sure how to call*;


    // fetch value from key-value pair and make it visible on TextView.
    String item = intent.getStringExtra("selected-item");
    cocktailName.setText(item);


    // fetch value from key-value pair and make it visible on ImageView.
    // ***** Trying to access thumbnail here...not happy *****
    cocktailImage.setImageResource(recipe.getDrinkId());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cocktail_display, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you getting response from Webservice ?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be letting your custom class implement Serializable interface and then you can pass object instances in intent extra using putExtra(Serializable..) variant of the Intent#putExtra() method.[try this link](http://hmkcode.com/android-passing-java-object-another-activity/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this wonderful website = http://www.parcelabler.com/

There, paste your 'model class' code and in output you will get something like this -

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DrinkRecipeModel implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("idDrink")
private int drinkId;

@SerializedName("strDrink")
private String drinkName;

@SerializedName("categories")
private String drinkCategories;

@SerializedName("strDrinkThumb")
private String drinkThumb;

@SerializedName("ingredients")
private ArrayList<String> ingredients;

public int getDrinkId() {
    return drinkId;
}

public String getDrinkName(){
    return drinkName;
}

public String getDrinkCategories(){
    return drinkCategories;
}

public String getDrinkThumb(){
    return drinkThumb;
}

public ArrayList<String> getIngredients() { return ingredients; }


public void setDrinkId(int drinkId) { this.drinkId = drinkId; }

public void setDrinkName(String drinkName) { this.drinkName = drinkName; }

public void setDrinkCategories(String drinkCategories) {
    this.drinkCategories = drinkCategories;
}

public void setDrinkThumb(String drinkThumb) {
    this.drinkThumb = drinkThumb;
}

public void setIngredients(ArrayList<String> ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

protected DrinkRecipeModel(Parcel in) {
    drinkId = in.readInt();
    drinkName = in.readString();
    drinkCategories = in.readString();
    drinkThumb = in.readString();
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(ingredients, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        ingredients = null;
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(drinkId);
    dest.writeString(drinkName);
    dest.writeString(drinkCategories);
    dest.writeString(drinkThumb);
    if (ingredients == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(ingredients);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<DrinkRecipeModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DrinkRecipeModel>() {
    @Override
    public DrinkRecipeModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DrinkRecipeModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DrinkRecipeModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DrinkRecipeModel[size];
    }
};
```

Now replace your model class' code with above code, your model class is not 'parcelable'.
Hence you can now use -

```
myIntent.putExtra("receipe_item", drinkReceipeOBjectWhichIsParcelableNow);
```

which you can get back in next activity to show.